# Selecting older videos to pin to Profile Page

Tags: vimeo

How do you elect older videos to pin for your profile page? When I select Edit>Profile Videos I cannot select older videos to pin.

Answer (score 0):

Only videos you have uploaded that are set to "Public", or other public videos that you have been tagged/credited in can be pinned to your profile. See the Help Article here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224969888-Managing-your-Vimeo-profile#featured

If you're unable to pin videos to your Vimeo profile, I suggest contacting Vimeo Support: https://vimeo.com/help/contact